# Bitwise OR on unsigned int without warning

Tags: c, bitwise-or

I am trying to rewrite the following piece of code:

```
$ cat t.c 
int main()
{
  unsigned int i = 0;
  int v = 3;
  i |= v;
  return 0;
}
```

Using a recent gcc you should get the following warning:

```
$ gcc -Wconversion t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:5:3: warning: conversion to ‘unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
```

How should I rewrite the bitwise OR to avoid this warning while maintaining code readability. `unsigned int i` is something very deep in the library code, so I cannot change this to an int.

Comment: i think if in the lib all code uses `int` you should use also `int i`instead of `uint i` and the user of the code needs to check if this is a problem

Comment: can you change `int v`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should't change *from* `unsigned`, but *to* it. Bitwise operations are always best performed on `unsigned` variables.

Make `v` `unsigned`!

Comment: indeed that was easy, for some reason I thought bitwise operation was done on (signed) integer by default.